# Google bots visit disallowed pages

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

Following userAgent visits my url which is disallowed in robots.txt. However Google bot visit my page.

```
url: https://www.example.com/page?param=1
```

robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /page
```

userAgent

```
"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Comment: Google support - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961

Comment: This one also for testing robot.txt https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961

Comment: I have already tested there.  Apart from adsbot-Google, all of them are blocked.

Comment: Are you concerned about a page showing on Google? Or are you just looking through your logs and seeing a "Googlebot" user agent and curious about who chose to send a request using that user agent string? Is this causing an actual problem with your site?